# translator service or API that can support sharepoint projects?

Tags: sharepoint

Hi can anyone suggest a microsoft web page translator that will support sharepoint web page/part?
Other than Bing and weglot?

Answer (score 1):

For SharePoint, it is suggested to use Machine Translation Service:

[Machine Translation Services in SharePoint](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/general-development/machine-translation-services-in-sharepoint)

[Introduction to Machine Translation Services in SharePoint 2013](https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/wbaer/2012/11/12/introduction-to-machine-translation-services-in-sharepoint-2013/)